# WIX: take text from one textbox1 and concatenate it to other text in textbox2

Tags: wix

I have these two textbox's:

```
<Control Id="textBox1" Type="Edit" Height="15" Width="180" X="150" Y="133" Property="P1" />

<Control Id="textBox2" Type="Edit" Height="15" Width="180" X="150" Y="158" Property="P2" />

<Property Id="P1" Value="" Secure="yes" Hidden="yes"/>
<Property Id="P2" Value="x" Secure="yes" Hidden="yes"/>
```

I want to take text from textbox1 and concatenate it to textbox2 once the user enters something in textbox1. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

ex: textbox1: p
    textbox2: xp

Answer (score 0):

```
 <SetProperty Id="P1" Value="[P2]" After="LaunchConditions"></SetProperty>
```

Try that it might work..sequence it whereever it suits your installer..:) Are you looking the textbox to be updated straight away, As far as I know it is not possible so dual dialogs will be your best option to achieve what you are looking.

Comment: Your going to have to create the exact replica dialog, I do this myself and you would barely notice it is another dialog.:)